# Открыть файл hosts при помощи объекта std::ofstream

Tags: c++, windows

Я работаю над программой, одна из задач которой - редактировать файл `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Смогу ли я открыть его при помощи объекта `std::ofstream`, если перед этим будет выполнена команда `system("net user администратор /active:yes")`? Или необходимо сделать все как-то по-другому?

Comment: А попробовать самостоятельно?